# Need to parse the json array using php

Tags: php, json

i have a json array like below,

```
{
    "months": {
        "1": ["1"],
        "2": ["10"]
    },
    "days": {
        "1": ["1", "2"],
        "2": ["2", "3"]
    }
}
```

i need to parse this in php. Need months and days values.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You did not search before posting

Comment: just use json_decode($json, true) ; it will convert json into array

Comment: Thanks bro @GautamRai..

Answer (score -1):

why you don't use json_decode() function?

```
$json = '{
"months": {
    "1": ["1"],
    "2": ["10"]
},
"days": {
    "1": ["1", "2"],
    "2": ["2", "3"]
}
}';

$decoded = json_decode($json);
var_dump($decoded);
```